# How can I find the size of an entire online open directory?

Tags: filesize, directory-structure, rclone

I would like to know the total size of an open directory online. How can I do this?

An example use-case might be to find out how large a repository mirror would be.

How can I find the total size of open directories such as:
http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/, or http://download.kiwix.org/, or http://apollo.sese.asu.edu/data/?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a fairly quick and simple way to find the size of any open directory online.

### TL;DR

Install rclone and replace the URL with whatever you want.

**Install Rclone** (Binaries available [here](https://rclone.org/downloads/))

```
curl https://rclone.org/install.sh | sudo bash
```

**Get Directory Size** (Replace URL with any open directory, make sure not to remove `:http:`)

```
rclone size --http-url http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ :http:
```

### Explanation

Using [rclone](https://rclone.org/downloads/) + [http](https://rclone.org/http/) with optional [mount](https://rclone.org/commands/rclone_mount/) will do the trick.

This gives you the freedom to check the size with all sorts of methods.
`rclone size http:`
or
`rclone mount http: directory/` then `cd directory/` and `du -sh` or `du -hd1` or `ncdu` ([from here](https://askubuntu.com/a/57760/702541)) or (NOT recommended) `ls -shR`

**Be Kind**

You might want to avoid hammering the server by adjusting the values and optionally adding/removing `--fast-list` in this command:

`rclone size http: -v --tpslimit 5 --bwlimit 500K --checkers 5 --fast-list`

Adjust up or down according to your needs and what you think the server can handle. For example, in just a couple minutes, I was able to use `rclone size` on a server that I thought would be fine with it, and got these results returned.

**Examples**

```
$ rclone size --http-url http://apollo.sese.asu.edu/data/ :http: --checkers 100

Total objects: 195669
Total size: 123.619 TBytes (135920738673216 Bytes)

$ rclone size --http-url http://download.kiwix.org :http: --checkers 100
Total objects: 24624
Total size: 5.711 TBytes (6279328743124 Bytes)
```